# Can't get inputstream from opend url?

Tags: java, httpurlconnection

I am trying to send sms from my web application using sms gateway. In the below code `con.getInputStream();` is not working when ever the control comes there program throws exception.

```
public String process_sms(String mob_no,String message) throws IOException, KeyManagementException, NoSuchAlgorithmException
    {       
        message=URLEncoder.encode(message, "UTF-8");                
        URL url = new URL("https://instantalerts.co/api/web/send/?apikey=6d6ra0u305nggr0cvrxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&sender=xxxxxx&to=xxxxxxxxxx&message=Your One Time Password is {$No} ");
        System.out.println("url look like " + url );
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        System.out.println("url opend"  );
        con.setRequestMethod("GET");
        System.out.println("url method"  );
        con.setDoOutput(true);
        System.out.println("url output"  );
        con.getOutputStream();
        System.out.println("url ouotput2"  );
       con.getInputStream();
        System.out.println("url input"  );
        BufferedReader rd;
        String line;
        String result = "";
        rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
        System.out.println("url input reader"  );
       while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null)
        {
           System.out.println("url input line"  );
           result += line;
        }
        rd.close(); 
        System.out.println("Result is" + result);
        return result;              
    }
```

In console it prints till `url ouotput2` after that `con.getInputStream();` not working. I don't know what is an issue.Can any one help me to fix this.

**error:**

```
type Exception report

message Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: https://instantalerts.co/api/web/send/?apikey=6d6ra0u305nggr0cvrxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&sender=xxxxx&to=xxxxxxxxx&message=Your One Time Password is {$No}

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: https://instantalerts.co/api/web/send/?apikey=6d6ra0u305nggr0cvrxxxxxxxxxxxxx&sender=xxxxxx&to=xxxxxxxxxxx&message=Your One Time Password is {$No}
    sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1628)
    sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:254)
    send_sms.process_sms(send_sms.java:92)
    send_sms.doPost(send_sms.java:58)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)

note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.62 logs.
```

I mentioned "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" in 'apikey','sender' and 'to' parameter in url.but in my program i use what ever it was given by the gateway provider.

Comment: HTTP return code 403 means "forbidden". I guess either your URL or your apikey is wrong.

Comment: @ThomasStets no i just copy and past the url in browser tab it working fine.

Comment: @KVK 403 means forbidden. You are doing something wrong with apikey or url. Possible checks headers as well for certain cookies.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you get the OutputStream at all? And then not send something? That's working for request-method POST only.

Just as well, you open input stream *twice* - where's that second stream supposed to come from?

Try it this way:

```
public String process_sms(String mob_no,String message) throws IOException, KeyManagementException, NoSuchAlgorithmException
{       
    message=URLEncoder.encode(message, "UTF-8");                
    URL url = new URL("https://instantalerts.co/api/web/send/?apikey=6d6ra0u305nggr0cvrxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&sender=xxxxxx&to=xxxxxxxxxx&message=Your One Time Password is {$No} ");
    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    System.out.println("url opend"  );
    String line;
    String result = "";
    BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
    System.out.println("url input reader: " + rd);
   while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null)
    {
       System.out.println("url input line"  );
       result += line;
    }
    rd.close(); 
    System.out.println("Result is" + result);
    return result;              
}
```

Comment: I tired that but it shows me invalid template error.because i am using trail account of sms gateway .

Comment: So now you do get something back from SMS gateway? So issue with *InputStream* seems resolved?

Answer (score 0):

Your API URL is considered only till word *"your"* as below:

```
https://instantalerts.co/api/web/send/?apikey=6d6ra0u305nggr0cvrxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&sender=xxxxxx&to=xxxxxxxxxx&message=Your
```

Because of space between message words so it is responding with 403 Error

So, You have to encode the url using URLEncoder :

```
String message = URLEncoder.encode("Your One Time Password is {$No}", "UTF-8");
URL url = new URL("https://instantalerts.co/api/web/send/?apikey=6d6ra0u305nggr0cvrxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&sender=xxxxxx&to=xxxxxxxxxx&message=" + message);
```